# How to prove $\mathbf{M}/r$ is a continuously differentiable vector field?

Tags: functions, continuity, improper-integrals, vector-fields, divergence-operator

I had previously asked a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3142511/showing-volume-and-surface-integration-is-unaffected-by-the-singularity-at-mat/3143901?143901) regarding the applicability of divergence theorem.

$\mathbf{M'}$ is a continuous vector field in volume $V'$ (which is compact and has a piecewise smooth boundary $S$). Consider the following integral:

$$\int_V \nabla . \left( \dfrac{\mathbf{M}}{r} \right) dV$$

with $(r=0) \in V$.

The answer says that, since the integrand is infinite at $(r=0)$, if we redefine our integral as:

$$\lim \limits_{\delta \to 0} \int_{V-\delta} \nabla . \left( \dfrac{\mathbf{M}}{r} \right) dV$$

where $\delta$ is a volume surrounding the point $(r=0)$

then we can apply $GDT$.

But that is only condition. How can we ensure $\dfrac{\mathbf{M}}{r}$ is a continuously differentiable vector field?

> **Edit:**
>
> **Comment :** "Is $\mathbf{M}$ continuously differentiable?"
>
> Maybe... But break it down into two cases: $(i)$ $\mathbf{M}$ is continuously differentiable   $(ii)$  $\mathbf{M}$ is continuous

Please show whether $\dfrac{\mathbf{M}}{r}$ is a continuously differentiable vector field in the two cases.

Comment: Is $\mathbf{M}$ continuously differentiable?

Comment: @RRL: Please have a look at the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $r = \|\mathbf{x}\|$ and the Euclidean norm is a continuous function from $\mathbb{R}^3$ into $\mathbb{R}$ since by the reverse triangle inequality

$$|\, \|\mathbf{x}\| - \|\mathbf{x}_0\|\,| \leqslant \|\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_0\|.$$

Hence, $\mathbf{x} \mapsto \frac{1}{r}$ is continuous in any region that excludes the origin.  You can show this with an $\epsilon - \delta$ argument, or just quote the theorem that continuity of $f$ with domain in $\mathbb{R}$ implies continuity of $1/f$ on any set where $f(x) \neq 0$.

Since $\mathbf{M}$ is continuous, so too is $\mathbf{x} \mapsto \frac{\mathbf{M}(\mathbf{x})}{r}$, since with $r_0 = \mathbf{x}_0$ we have

$$\left\|\frac{\mathbf{M}(\mathbf{x})}{r} -  \frac{\mathbf{M}(\mathbf{x}_0)}{r_0}\right\| \leqslant \frac{1}{r}\|\mathbf{M}(\mathbf{x})-\mathbf{M}(\mathbf{x}_0)\|+ \|\mathbf{M}(\mathbf{x}_0)\|\left|\frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{r_0} \right|,$$

and $\mathbf{M}(\mathbf{x}_0)$ and $1/r$ are bounded in any compact neighborhood of $\mathbf{x}_0$.

For continuous differentiability you need $\mathbf{M}$ to be continuously differentiable unless some removable discontinuity arises. It remains to show  that $\mathbf{x} \mapsto \frac{1}{r}$ is continuously differentiable which amounts to showing that the partial derivatives are continuous by an argument similar to that given above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sir.... However what bothers me is that by just stating electric field $\mathbf{E}$ is continuous (rather than continuously differentiable), the divergence theorem is applied to vector field $\mathbf{E}$. How is it justifible?

Comment: @Joe: You're welcome.  I don't know where you are seeing this.  Perhaps "they" are not stating the hypotheses carefully, which is not uncommon in a physics setting. It is usually safe to assume that a physical entity like the electric field is specified by a function sufficiently smooth for the divergence theorem to apply. Furthermore it is sufficient but not necessary that the vector field be continuously differentiable for the theorem to apply.  See, for example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2852090/148510) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2344225/148510).

Comment: In your link it is said "Continuity of the partial derivatives is strong sufficient condition". Almost all of the physics textbook (which gives a brief introduction to mathematical physics) like Griffiths (page 31) just writes down the equation without a statement. Other elementary mathematical physics textbooks uses the "strong sufficient condition" discussed above. Late 19th century physics textbooks do make the statement about $GDT$ (along with elementary proofs) but doesn't mention anything about "continuity of partial derivatives".

Comment: Please see [here](https://archive.org/details/ATreatiseOnElectricityMagnetism-Volume1/page/n51) as well as [here](https://archive.org/details/2mathematicalthe00jeanuoft/page/156). Are these statements sufficient in order to apply $GDT$ for electric field $\mathbf{E}$ and $\frac{\mathbf{M}}{r}$?

Comment: @Joe:  I would not expect 19th century books and papers to specify these conditions carefully.  They are about the (important) physics content and assume tacitly that there is enough regularity for the theorem to hold. To be honest I'm not entirely sure what the question is anymore.

Comment: Here is my thinking on this.  If the author applies the divergence theorem to an electric field (1) differentiability must be assumed, i.e., enough that the divergence is define; (2) the divergence must be integrable.  If we further assume that the field is continuously differentiable then we are good, but we don't really need that continuity as I pointed out.  Now think about the source of the electric field -- if it is the result of a charge distribution with a continuous or piecewise continuous density, then it can be shown that the potential is continuous and differentiable.

Comment: I may be wrong here but I think we can go farther to show the electric field which is the gradient of the potential  must also be continuously differentiable.  Now have you ever seen a physics reference where the electric field is not assumed to be or, if explicitly presented, actually not smooth enough that the divergence theorem fails?

Comment: No...I think the conditions for divergence theorem must have been assumed tacitly.